# Dojo makes focus lost on clicked link after going back

Tags: javascript, firefox, dojo, focus

I have a page A containing a link to page B, after clicking the link then going back (pressing the Back button of Firefox browser), I want that the link still has the focus. It is the default behavior of Firefox. However, if page A uses Dojo (loads dojo.js), then this is broken, after going back nothing is in focus. How do I achieve this focus-preserving behavior even when using Dojo (which is required for the project)?